# <authentication mode="Windows" /> missing from my Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

If I create a Web API in Visual Studio 2013 and I select that I want "Individual User Accounts" type of authentication (which is the equivalent of the ASP.NET Identity), the web.config file will include the following line in its  section:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
```

However, if I select Windows Authentication as my choice for authentication, I would expect to see

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

in the web.config file, but I don't. Why is that? Is Windows Authentication the default setting so that when missing is implied by the server?

Thanks,
Ed

Answer (score 0):

None = no or custom.
Default = Windows.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291347%28v=vs.71%29.aspx